# What is a TTY and how can I enable it on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, stdout, tty

I'm currently setting up a node.js server and I'm using the debug module here https://github.com/visionmedia/debug.

I'm trying to enable it so I can get the colored debugging information in my output, however my terminal looks like the last terminal screen at the bottom after it says:

```
When stdout is not a TTY, Date#toUTCString() is used, making it more useful for logging the debug information as shown below:
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php Here you go. A thorough explanation of TTY.

Comment: You can set the env `DEBUG_COLORS` to force colored output. ref https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/commit/861fffaa9e369dd0284d0170f2400976dc924716

Comment: @DanD. Don't think that's been released yet. The [current version](https://npmjs.org/package/debug), [0.7.0](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/tree/0.7.0), is dated a few weeks before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tty is one of those funky Unix commands that prints (or, displays) to standard output the name of the terminal connected to standard input.

These are commonly used as a way to get access to the computer to fix things, without actually logging into a possibly b0rked desktop.

Related: What is tty7 in the commandline?

By default Ubuntu has 7 tty's.

1-6 are command line only, 7 runs your X session (your normal desktop).

To access them, use this keyboard shortcut:

Ctrl + Alt + F1

(changing F1 to F1-F6 to access the terminal that you need)

To get back to your X session (the normal desktop),

Ctrl + Alt + F7

Answer (score 1):

The TTY is the [terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_%28Unix%29) or command prompt itself.

The screenshots are demonstrating the different results when `stdout` is directed to the terminal/TTY (with colors and time diffs) vs. when it's redirected elsewhere, such as to a file (via `> out` and with timestamps).

It [determines](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/0.7.0/lib/debug.js#L54) which format to use with [`tty.isatty`](http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_tty_isatty_fd).

Note that not all terminals support the [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Support) it's using to [display colors](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/master/lib/debug.js#L115).